# How do you beat Up & Nova?

Tags: yooka-laylee

The high score of 14k seems almost impossible, so I'm wondering if I'm not getting how the game should be played.

So how can you beat Rextro's score in Up & Nova? What are techniques that should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you've just got to practice and get adept at capturing the quills while avoiding being hit. I just beat it this week, was hit once near the beginning, and still finished with a score around 18,000. Others, however, claim that scores upwards of [20,000](https://steamcommunity.com/app/360830/discussions/0/133262848294312277/) are possible.

On a more strategic note, I think the game is just extremely difficult, taking many hours of repetitive play to be able to beat Rextro. My advice is to **focus on dodging** the enemies more than grabbing the quills. Although the quills are what give you the points, getting hit (especially late in the mini-game) is disastrous, since as the thread above mentions, you can lose more than 5000 points from a single hit. And since you only need 14,000, grabbing *all* of the quills is unnecessary.

So I think strategically, it just requires some practice, as well as an understanding that avoiding enemies should be the top priority, as opposed to grabbing the quills.

Unfortunately, I suspect that you understand the strategy perfectly, and that you're now at the point in the game that is going to require some frustrating grinding.